# How to scan barcode in iPhone camera?

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am trying to test the barcode scanner in iPhone application. I have used the following code

```
   - (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    //  get the decode results
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];

    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
        // just grab the first barcode
        break;

    // showing the result on textview
    self.resultLbl.text = symbol.data;

    self.imgViewScan.image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // dismiss the controller
    [reader dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (IBAction)scanBtnTapped:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Scanning..");
    self.resultLbl.text = @"Scanning..";
    ZBarReaderViewController *codeReader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    codeReader.readerDelegate=self;
    codeReader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = codeReader.scanner;
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 0];

    [self presentViewController:codeReader animated:YES completion:nil];  
   }
```

This code is not working on simulator.

Comment: not working means what are facing. give a clear notes

Comment: "This code is not working on simulator." You have to use real device to test this feature.

Comment: You can't simulate camera on iPhone simulator, for launching UIImagepicker with camera please run your app on real device.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Download the code of barcode scanner

https://github.com/stephenkeep/barcode_scanner

Answer (score 1):

If you require iOS 7, you don't need third party SDKs like ZXing to scan bar codes. Scanning common bar code types is built in to iOS via the new `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject`. Someone wrote a simple [demo app](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2013/10/10/scanning-barcodes-with-ios-7-objective-c.aspx) that shows how to add it. It's simple, and works very well.